# Can I "autowired" in a class extending another one (SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler)?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a class that exctend SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler.

I tried to autowired another one of my class, annotated as @Component, but when I call this class (the extended one) I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.springgestioneerrori.loginhandler.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java:33)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:329)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:294)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

this is the class that extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler

```
 package com.springgestioneerrori.loginhandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.springgestioneerrori.struttura.Menu;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {     


    @Autowired
    Menu menu;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, javax.servlet.ServletException{         

       menu.prova();   <------ here menu is null       

       Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();

       Iterator<SimpleGrantedAuthority> i = authorities.iterator();

        while(i.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(i.next().toString());
        }       

        System.out.println("sto onAuthenticationSuccess");
        super.setDefaultTargetUrl("/index");        
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }

}
```

The Menu class

```
package com.springgestioneerrori.struttura; 


@Component
public class Menu { 
    public void prova(){
        System.out.println("prova");
    }

}
```

This is a piece of code of web-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springgestioneerrori.struttura"/> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springgestioneerrori.loginhandler"/>
```

security config

```
....
    <form-login 
                    login-page="/login"         
                    default-target-url="/index" 
                    always-use-default-target="true"
                    authentication-success-handler-ref="customSuccessHandler"                 
                    authentication-failure-handler-ref="customFailureHandler"   
                    username-parameter="j_username"         
                    password-parameter="j_password" />
....

    <beans:bean id="customSuccessHandler" class="com.springgestioneerrori.loginhandler.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
```

......

Whene debugging, menu is null

[image]
What's the problem?

Comment: Please show the code where you configure that success handler with the null field (add it to Spring Security, etc.).

Comment: I added all the code, spring-security.xml as well. Anyway, all my project work perfectly, if i didn't "call" a method from the class Menu i don't have any problem

Comment: How do get the instance of `CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler`? Do you create one by using `new` or is it "autowired" in another class?

Comment: there is this bean inside spring-security.xml <beans:bean id="customSuccessHandler" class="com.springgestioneerrori.loginhandler.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

Comment: I'm not being able to see the issue. Please try refactoring your handler to use constructor injection instead of field injection and see whether that identifies any problems.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get. Whats should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. Assume this is your `Menu` declaration inside `CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

```
private Menu menu;

public Menu getMenu() {
    return menu;
}

public void setMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu= menu;
}
```

Now we can use property injection here. Inside security config

```
<beans:bean id="menu" class="menu path goes here....">
</beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="customSuccessHandler" class="com.springgestioneerrori.loginhandler.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
<beans:property name="menu" ref="menu"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Now it should fix your problem.